# JavaScript Back Button Failure

Tags: javascript, dom, button, back

So I thought this script was pretty straight forward:

```
<a id="BackButtonlnk" href="#" class="white" onClick="history.go(-1)"></a>
```

When I click it it briefly shows the previous page but just looks like it refreshes
and you never end up at the previous page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding "; return false" to your onclick.

I think what's happening is the onclick fires (trying to go to the previous page), and then the browser tries to go to "(current page)#" (note the "#"), and essentially refreshes the original page. Thus, it appears that it's going back and forth - because it is.

```
<a id="BackButtonlnk" href="#" class="white" onClick="history.go(-1); return false;"></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the href instead of the onclick event:

```
<a id="BackButtonlnk" class="white" href="javascript:history.go(-1);">Go Back</a>
```

Comment: This is a perfectly workable solution as well. I just prefer to give the href a good URL, in case users have JavaScript turned off.

Comment: Is a "#" really considered a good URL? Sure it doesn't crash the browser, but it's not exactly a functioning page.

Answer (score 0):

**In Javascript has many forms.**

```
<a id="BackButtonlnk" class="white" href="javascript:history.back(-1);">Go Back</a>
```

***If you wanna do that you write, recomend***

```
<a id="BackButtonlnk" class="white" href="javascript:history.go(-1);"></a>
```

Comment: **With 'javascript:' into href running in all browsers.**

Comment: **PSI.:** If you try with **href='#'** and **onclick** with function running.
**BUT** in any browsers **MAY don't running**. **Recomend 'href="javascript:'**.